# How to show calendar view with day/weak/month wise?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to show an appointment in a calendar in my android app, like image bellow. When user click on day then calendar show day view and when user click on weak then calendar show weak view and same for month also. I have search on internet but could not find perfect solution for this. How can I achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: your calendar look like weak :)

Comment: Earlier i have created calender and show monthly view but now i want to change view on same activity so I am not getting how it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like this : [AgendaCalendarView](https://github.com/Tibolte/AgendaCalendarView)